# how to edit threeTenAbp library

Tags: java, android, jar, localdate, threetenbp

I'm using threeTenAbp library to create a calendar.
but I need to change some codes in 'LocalDate.java', a class of threeTenAbp library.

I clicked in 'copy path' and get this address:
`C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.threeten\threetenbp\1.3.7\ec01f510a0f0ad5013dfb652510ea07fc2b23321\threetenbp-1.3.7-sources.jar!\org\threeten\bp\LocalDate.java`

so I opened jar file with WinRAR and edited 'LocalDate.java' but still Android Studio use the original version and it seems my changing has no effect.
for example, it shows a message which I comment it!

how can I edit this library?

Comment: "but I need to change some codes in 'LocalDate.java'" -- I strongly recommend finding some other solution for your problem, unless you want to keep re-integrating your changes as ThreeTenBP is updated. "how can I edit this library?" -- use the source code from [its GitHub repo](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp).

Comment: I am curious as to what your real problem is that makes you want to modify `LocalDate.java`. We can probably find a better solution if your share your context.